# How to get a Provider from an Element of type Binding in Guice?

Tags: java, guice

`Binding` interface contains a method `getProvider()` that should do the conversion to a `Provider`. However most of implementations are based on [`BindingImpl`](https://github.com/google/guice/blob/6.0.0/core/src/com/google/inject/internal/BindingImpl.java#L70) that allows for getting a `Provider` only when an injector is available or when the binding is defined using a provider. Otherwise `UnsupportedOperationException` is throw.

How to reliably obtain a `Provider` corresponding to a `Binding` before an injector in created?

Or more generally how to use a `Binding` element as a source of value in my custom `Provider`?

Context: A library that I'd like to uses, exposes a Guice [`Module`](https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/6.0.0/javadoc/com/google/inject/Module.html) through which it integrates with the main app. I'd like to conditionally re-map selected services of that library. Methods of [`Elements`](https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/6.0.0/javadoc/com/google/inject/spi/Elements.html) class allow to cherry-pick bindings. I'd like to convert a selected [`Binding`](https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/6.0.0/javadoc/com/google/inject/Binding.html) to a [`Provider`](https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/6.0.0/javadoc/com/google/inject/Provider.html) so that it can be conditionally use it in my own provider.